# How to handle user approval in browser geolocation with Gmap?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-maps, geolocation

I'm building a HTML5 geolocation function along with Gmaps.

I'm having a small issue when waiting for the user approval to be geolocated: The user is asked by the browser wether or not he wants to be geolocated. When he clicks yes, he is geolocated but the gmap thing isn't triggered and the map is not displayed on the screen. Then, if he refresh it, everything is working fine. This particulary happen on mobile phone.

I give a piece of the code when handling the geolocation thing:

```
    <script>
    // <!-- GOOGLE MAPS & POSITION -->

    var radius = 1;
    var map;
    var position;

    jQuery(window).ready(function(){ 
        //If we click on Find me Lakes
        jQuery("#btnInit").click(initiate_geolocation);
        initiate_geolocation();

        $('#radius').change(function(v){
            handle_geolocation_query(position);
        });
    });

    function initiate_geolocation() { 
        if (navigator.geolocation)  
        {  
            var script = document.createElement("script");
            script.type = "text/javascript";
            script.src = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBbfJJVh0jL1X9b7XFDcPuV7nHD1HlfsKs&sensor=true&callback=initialize";
            document.body.appendChild(script);
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(append_google_map, handle_errors);
        }  
        else  
        {  
            yqlgeo.get('visitor', normalize_yql_response);
        }  
    }

    function handle_errors(error)  
    {  
        switch(error.code)  
        {  
            case error.PERMISSION_DENIED: alert("user did not share geolocation data");  
            break;  
            case error.POSITION_UNAVAILABLE: alert("could not detect current position");  
            break;  
            case error.TIMEOUT: alert("retrieving position timedout");  
            break;  
            default: alert("unknown error");  
            break;  
        }  
    }  

    function append_google_map(pos){ 

        position = pos;

        var mapOptions = {
            zoom: 15,
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude),
            streetViewControl: false,
            mapTypeId : google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        }

        if (typeof map == 'undefined') { //We make sure the map object hasn't been toogled to the page

            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("gmap"), mapOptions);

            //$('#gmap').slideToggle('slow');

            setMarkerPosition(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);

        }

        handle_geolocation_query();
    }
```

As you can see here, I'm initiating the geolocation stuff in the initiate function with an error callback and a success callback. That's when a pop up appears on the user's screen to ask if he approves the geolocation. Even if he clicks yes, it seems that some part of the code is not triggered (or we are redirected to handle_errors dunno) and therefore, the maps doesn't appear on the screen (it is handled a bit further in the code in the append_google_map.

Could anyone help me to figure why this is happening and how to handle this please ?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't, it's a security feature. Your code must wait for the user to approve or decline whether they want to share their location or not.

Your code must be able to react upon both responses from the user. If they chose not to share your code, you could try to fallback to the coordinates of the city, or display some message.

It is ok to have a message on the page telling them to share their location, provided that you explain to them why they are sharing their location with you.

Comment: Hey, thanks Samer, but I've already understood and implemented that part, look at my code. My issue is more like the script not triggering successfully once the user has accepted to be geolocated. I think I'm missing something in there where `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(append_google_map, handle_errors);` doesn't call "append_google_map" when the user accept to be geolocated. Once he clicks on okay, geolocate me, then nothing happen. Why ? is calling a success function the correct way to handle it ? Thx

Comment: Could be because the Google Maps library hasn't loaded yet. If you see in your URL to load the library, at the end you have a `callback=initialize`, so try making a function called initialize in your JS and make sure it's accessible by global scope or `window.initialize = function...` and place your geolocation inside of that. That's how I usually do it.